# Delphi Indy IdTcpClient read operation returning truncated data for one specific request

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy

This is an interesting problem that I’ve not been able to solve yet.

I am writing a client that communicates across the Internet to a server. I am using the TIdTcpClient Internet Direct (Indy) component in Indy 10 using RAD Studio 2007 native personality.

To get data from the server, I issue an HTTP request using SSL over port 443 where my request details are contained in the HTTP message body. So far, so good. The code works like charm, with one exception.

There is one request that I am submitting that should produce a response of about 336 KB from the server (the HTTP response header contains Content-Length: 344795). The problem is that I am getting only 320KB back. The response, which is in XML, is clearly truncated in the middle of an XML element.

For what it’s worth, the XML is simple text. There are no special characters that can account for the truncation. My TIdTcpClient component is simply reporting that, after receiving the partial response, that the server closed the connection gracefully (which is how every response is expected to be completed, even those that are not truncated, so this is not a problem).

I can make nearly identical calls to the same server where the response is also more than a few K bytes, and all of these work just fine. One request I make returns about 850 KB, another returns about 300 KB, and so on.

In short, I encounter this problem only with the one specific request. All other requests, of which there are many, receive a complete response.

I have talked to the creator of the service, and have supplied examples of my request. He reported that the request is correct. He also told me that when he issues my same request to his server that he gets a complete response.

I’m at a loss. Either the creator of the service is mistaken, and there is actually a problem with the response on that end, or there is something peculiar about my request.

Is there a solution here that I'm missing? Note that I’ve also used a number of other read mechanisms (ReadString, ReadStrings, ReadBytes, etc) and all produce the same result, a truncation of this one specific response at the 320KB mark.

The code is probably not relevant, but I’ll include it anyway. Sorry, but I cannot include the XML request, as it includes proprietary information. (ReadTimeout is set to 20 seconds, but the request returns in about 1 second, so it's not a timeout issue.)

```
function TClient.GetResponse(PayloadCDS: TClientDataSet): String;
var
  s: String;
begin
  try
    try
      s := GetBody(PayloadCDS);
      IdTcpClient1.Host := Host;
      IdTcpClient1.Port := StrToInt(Port);
      IdTcpClient1.ReadTimeout := ReadTimeout;
      IdTcpClient1.Connect;
      IdTcpClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      //IdTcpClient1.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize := 2000000;
      IdTcpClient1.IOHandler.Write(s);
      Result := IdTcpClient1.IOHandler.AllData;
    except
      on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
      begin
         //eat the exception
      end;
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if IdTcpClient1.Connected then
      IdTcpClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my original question, this connection uses SSL. This requires that you use an IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component, which you assign to the IOHandler property of the IdTcpClient component. All of this was in my original design, and as I mentioned, many of my requests were being responded to correctly.

Over the weekend I discovered another request which was returning an incomplete response. I captured that original HTTP request, and using a tool called SOAP UI, I submitted that request to the server. Using SOAP UI, the server returned a complete answer. Clearly, something was wrong with my client, and not the server.

I finally found the solution by just fiddling around with various properties. The property that finally corrrected the problem was in the SSLOptions property of the IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL class. The default value of SSLOptions.Method is sslvSSLv2. When I changed Method to sslvSSLv23, all responses returned complete.

Why I was able to retrieve some responses in full and not all before I made this change is still a mystery to me. Nonetheless, setting IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method to sslvSSLv23 solved my problem.

Thank you Remy Lebeau, for your suggestions.

Comment: TIdHTTP supports SSL the same way TIdTCPClient does - by assigning an SSL-enabled IOHandler before connecting.  You really should be using the TIdHTTP component for handling HTTP traffic.  That is why it exists in the first place.

Comment: Also, in the current Indy 10 version, the default value of the SSLOptions.Method property is not sslvSSLv2, it is sslvTLSv1.  It does make sense that setting the Method to sslvSSLv23 would clear up some errors, though.  When the Method is set to anything other than sslvSSLv23, than the other party *must* be using that specific SSL version on its end or else the SSL handshake will fail.  sslvSSLv23, on the other hand, is more of a catch-all wildcard that supports all SSL versions from SSLv2 through TLSv1, and allows both parties to negotiate a compatible SSL version.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending an HTTP request, you should be using the TIdHTTP component instead of the TIdTCPClient component directly.  There are a lot of details about the HTTP protocol that TIdHTTP manages for you that you would have to handle manually if you continue using TIdTCPClient directly.

If you are going to continue using TIdTCPClient directly, then you should at least stop using the TIdIOHandler.AllData() method.  Extract the 'Content-Length' reply header (you can Capture() the headers into a TStringList or TIdHeaderList and then use its Values[] property) and then pass the actual reported byte count to either TIdIOHandler.ReadString() or TIdIOHandler.ReadStream().  That will help ensure that the reading I/O does not stop reading prematurely because of the server's disconnect at the end of the reply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I initially used the TIdHTTP component, but found that I needed the additional control that the TIdTcpClient component provided.

I will try the Capture approach to see if that can resolve the problem, but I am doubtful, given that all of my other requests are handled correctly. It will be a day or so before I can try your suggestion.

Again, thank you.

I will

Comment: I tried Capture, but it does not seem to provide a solution. When I called capture, it captures until the connection is closed by the server. By then it's too late to set the byte count.

AllData is working fine in this case. In fact, when I ReadStream and set the AReadUntilDisconnect parameter to True I get the same response as when I use AllData.

I am going to be talking with the creator of the service to see if maybe the problem is on their end.

Comment: What kind of extra control do you need exactly?  As for Capture(), the only way it would continue capturing until disconnect is if you are calling it with the wrong parameter values.  The default terminator is a line with a single '.' character on it.  HTTP headers, on the other hand, are terminated by a blank line instead.  So you would need to pass a blank string to Capture()'s ADelim parameter.